# Dark Mode and Visualforce templates

Tags: email, visualforce-template, gmail

I have been looking for a solution to be able to show the email body with white text and black background when the dark mode is enabled. But so far I haven't seen any solution that is actually working ..
I tried with following this guide but nothing : https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/dark-mode-for-email/

Is there anyone who had this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i found out is a trick to not let the dark mode convert the background from white to black. Simply use a background colour that is almost white but not exactly white, just with a 1% difference, this way it won't get converted to black.

Edit : doesn't work 100%, i think that it even depends if it's a system dark mode, a browser one or addon.